# Не отображается абсолютно позиционированный dropdown-menu в bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap4, dropdown

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Не отображается dropdown-menu в bootstrap4, хотя скрипт работает и элемент при нажатии на ссылку появляется на странице, но его не видно. Проблема только с абсотютно позиционированным dropdown-menu (relative, static отображаются корректно). В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Чтобы позиционировать absolute у родителя тоже должен быть задан position. Поставьте родителю position: relative;

Comment: все задано - и position: relative родителю, и z-index

Comment: в онлайне сайт есть? вживую посмотреть

Comment: http://bjccny.alef.im/

Comment: пока только к "lyfe-cycle" выпадающее меню добавлено

Comment: у класса .navbar-nav стоит overflow: hidden поэтому, все что выходит за его пределы не отображается, в том числе и выпадающее вниз меню

Comment: верно, спасибо)